# Trying to Get Footer Outside of Container In MVC 4 Web App

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc-4

By nature, when using Visual Studio 2017 to create an MVC 4 application, the footer is constrained within a div with a class `container body-content` in _layout.cshtml. Of course, this makes the footer constrained within the div:

[image]

But what we want is for the footer to extend the entire width of the page, just like the header.

When I comment out the div,

[image]

the footer gets 100% of the width, but now so does everything else in the body:

[image]

Also there's a bunch of blank, white space beneath the footer. Here's the entire code for _layout.cshtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/Style.css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="navbar-gradient">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <!--<img src="~/images/lion-logo.png" />-->
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <img src="~/images/lion-logo.png" id="logo"/>
                @Html.ActionLink("LION TECHNOLOGIES", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand", @id = "logo-text" })
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-gradient">
            <!--hide links-->
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="hidden">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Reports", "Index", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Accounts", "About", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Settings", "Contact", "Home")</li>
            </ul>
            @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

   <!-- <div class="container body-content">-->
    @RenderBody()
    <!--<hr />-->
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - <img src="~/images/lion-logo.png" id="logo-footer" /> LION TECHNOLOGIES</p>
    </footer> 
    <!--</div>-->

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

</body>
</html>
```

I've also tried wrapping everything just inside the `<body>` `</body>` tags with the `container body-content` div but that didn't have any effect. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I'm still new to C#, I didn't realize that the line `@RenderBody()` renders the entire body section on its own. All I needed to do was this:

```
<div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
    <!--<hr />-->
</div>
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - <img src="~/images/lion-logo.png" id="logo-footer" /> LION TECHNOLOGIES</p>
    </footer>     

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

</body>
</html>
```

Close the div after `@RenderBody()`

Answer (score 3):

If you are using bootstrap 3 then try to remove footer from the div which has class container and after that make another div after with class continer-fluid and put your footer code inside. `.container` is fixed width and `.container-fluid` is full width. Please see the grid system of bootstrap 3 http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

```
<div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <hr />
    <footer>
          <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - <img src="~/images/lion-logo.png" id="logo-footer" /> LION TECHNOLOGIES</p>
    </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: @HappyHands31 if its work for you then can you mark it as answer ,please?